# GetFileAsync Exception

Tags: c#, windowsphone

Метод должен сохранить mp3 файл из установленного пакета в пользовательскую папку с помощью `FileSavePicker`. Предварительно, как в примерах, использую `GetFileAsync`, принимающего в качестве параметра путь к файлу, чтобы указать, какой именно файл необходимо сохранить. После того, как метод запускается, приложение останавливается на :

```
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
```

В коде ошибки указывается, что параметр задан неверно.

```
private async void pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string path = "Assets/Sounds/news.mp3";
    StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);

    var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
    savePicker.SuggestedSaveFile = file;
    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("SoundFile",new List<string>() { ".mp3" });
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "SoundFile";
    StorageFile newRingtone = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    if (newRingtone !=null)
        ...
}
```

Не совсем понимаю, что не так с путём к файлу. Или я вообще неверно понял суть инструмента и необходимо использовать какой-то другой?

Comment: Может, оно ожидает backslash? А может, такого файла нет. Дайте точное исключение и информацию из него.

Comment: Как насчет `"Assets\Sounds\news.mp3"`?

Comment: @andreycha, забыли `@` или экранировать слэши :)

Comment: @Grundy да уж догадается.

Comment: А что за ошибка конкретная? и что за код?

Comment: Если указывать путь как     @"Assets\Sounds\news.mp3"  , то в сообщении ошибки указывается   "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"   - если я правильно понимаю, то доступ к файлам ,включенным в пакет , есть.   Если использовать путь,как указано в вопросе,то код ошибки следующий:      "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"

Comment: @selezen88: Ну так отлично. Так, как в вопросе, просто нельзя. А с backslash'ами можно. Но если у вас прав на этот файл нет, то уж никак не получится. Другой вопрос, _почему_ у вас нету прав на этот файл.

Comment: А вы точно уверены, что во втором случае исключение происходит в **той же** строке? Вангую, что вылетает, когда вы пытаетесь **записать** файл в каталог, где установлено приложение (туда нельзя, разумеется, это всё равно что писать в Program Files на десктопе).

Comment: @VladD , вы правы - отвалился на строчке    PickSaveFileAsync   . Я не совсем понимаю, в чем именно ошибка: нет доступа на запись или на считывание файла? Если на считывание - то доступ к файлам,включенным в пакет есть. Если на запись - отваливается ведь еще до выбора конечной папки сохранения.

Comment: @selezen88: Нет доступа на запись, да. Думаю, что ` PickSaveFileAsync` не хочет начинать с каталога, куда запись запрещена. Может, убрать `savePicker.SuggestedSaveFile = file;` полностью?

Comment: @VladD, Если убрать эту строку, то FileSavePicker не получает файл для записи - приложении не отваливается,но в результате сохранения получается пустой файл.

Comment: @selezen88: Странно. А если в качестве стартового каталога/файла указать какой-нибудь в ApplicationData или где там можно писать юзеру?

Comment: Или попробуйте пример отсюда: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-save-a-file-with-a-picker, он должен работать.

Comment: @selezen88 а что не так с пустым файлом-то? Задача `PickSaveFileAsync` - это выбрать файл, дальше вы можете записывать в него что угодно.

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, если у вас вопрос связан с ошибкой, надо сделать следующее:

1. Воспроизведите ошибку, т.е. остановиться на ней в отладке.
2. Открывайте отладочное окно `Watch` и добавьте в него вот такой запрос:

   `new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString()`
3. Из поля `Value` возьмите результат выполнения и предложите его общественности, должно получиться что-то вроде:

Стэк:

```
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at AIStorePortableService1.CFileSystemAsyncWrapper.<GetFileAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
at AIStorePortableService1.CFileSystemAsyncWrapper.GetFileAsync(StorageFolder iFolder, String iFileName)
at AIStorePortableService1.CStoreFileSystem.AIPortableService2.IFileSystem.FileDataRead(StorageTypesEnum iStorageType, String iPath)
at AIPortableService2.CFileSystem.FileDataRead(StorageTypesEnum iStorageType, String iPath)
...
```

4. Открывайте окно `Output` в режиме `Debug` и в нём в самом нижу ищите что-то вроде:

Описание ошибки, его тоже надо представить общественности:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.
WinRT information: An item cannot be found with the specified name (Assets/Sounds/news.mp3).
```

Дальше будет много отладки и локализации беды и в конце концов станет понятно, что в WinRT относительный путь надо указывать так:

```
string path = @"Assets\Sounds\news.mp3"
```

Как это проверить не прибегая к мучительной отладке? Да очень просто. Посмотрите, что возвращает код:

```
string strPath = System.IO.Path.Combine("Assets", "Sounds", "news.mp3");
```

Едем дальше, вы пишите:

> Если указывать путь как @"Assets\Sounds\news.mp3" , то в сообщении ошибки указывается "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

А вы уверены, что эта ошибка происходит на той же строке кода? А не в тот ли момент, когда вы пытаетесь на этот файл натравить `FileSavePicker`? Записывать то в это место и действительно нельзя.